# Collect array of objects based on nested object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an array of products (objects). I want to get the biggest bang for your buck by obtaining the most Base with as little money as possible (in this case, $50). For the data set below, the correct outcome will contain an array of `foo` `bar` and `baz` products.

```
 "result": [
  {
   "name": "foo",
   "price": 20,
   "Base": 52,
  },
  {
   "name": "bar",
   "price": 12,
   "Base": 51,
  },
  {
   "name": "baz",
   "price": 15,
   "Base": 50,
  },
  {
   "name": "qux",
   "price": 10,
   "Base": 47,
  },
 ]
```

Originally I thought I would use a reducer with an initial accumulator of `[]`, but my products I have can range anywhere between 600 - 2000 products and I don't think it would be performant.ie

```
function selectProducts(results){
  let finalList = []
  let priceList = []
  results.forEach(function(product){
    let price = product.price
    let sum = priceList.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    if (product.price + sum <= 50){
      finalList.push(product);
      priceList.push(price);
    }
  })
  return finalList
}
```

I don't like this code because I'm keeping track of two arrays when I don't think I need to. As far as I can see, the output of the above is correct, however I'm curious to see if my implementation can be improved. thanks!!!

Comment: looks like a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: Exactly! Here's a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LusJS5-AGo) on it too.

Comment: There are many js solutions: https://gist.github.com/frobnitzem/28707410b81870e88925097fdfe1f85b

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want to do is keep track of the priceList. Then why not convert the forEach loop to reduce, and then the accumulator can be the priceList? You can choose internally if you want to add to the accumulating value, and then you can get rid of the internal reduce.

```
function selectProducts(results){
  let finalList = []
  results.reduce(function(acc, product){
    if (product.price + acc <= 50){
      finalList.push(product);
      return acc + product.price;
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }, 0)
  return finalList
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this, as well as the code in the original question, produce the wrong result for an array like this?

`[{"price": 45, "Base": 1}, {"price": 5, "Base": 2}, {"price": 50, "Base": 200}]`

Comment: I agree, it sounds like the knacksack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). I was only regarding the complexity of the function he suggested.